# How to implement a^b without `pow`?

Tags: c

I need to write a function to compute a^b but I am not allowed to use `pow`. Any ideas? I am lost. 
It looks like problem is in main now...
Somewhere it gets that vys is what i characterise it. So if i set that vys=1 in main i get 1 in output..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void multiplied(int b, int n)
{
  int i=1, vys=1;
  while (i<=n)
  {
    vys *=b;

    i++;
  }
  return vys;
}


main(void)
{
  int b=0, n=0, vys=1;
  printf("Give numbers b and n but they must be in interval <0,10>!\n");
  scanf("%d %d", &b, &n);
  if ((b < 0 || b>10) || (n<0 || n>10))
  {
    printf("Numbers are not in interval <0,10>!\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Number is in interval so i continue...\n");
    sleep(2);
   vys= multiplied(&b, &n);
    printf("%d", vys);
}
```

Comment: Are you comfortable with reading something like `*b**b` ? I am not.

Comment: First thing to do (and this is really important): format your code correctly, like the samples in your C text book.

Comment: eugene i don´t know how else can i write that, any ideas?

Comment: What are you lost on? Is it going wrong? If so , how?

Comment: Well, since the logic is wrong, you just don't need to write it. a) Initialize `i` and `vys`. b) Each iteration multiply `vys` by `*b`. c) It is not clear why you need to pass pointers at all.

Comment: Don't be shy about putting a printf statement in the while loop in your fiunction to see what happens.

Comment: thanks for advices, i did try that eugene but i still got answer i did not want.. I always get vys=0 even if i remove *

Comment: Set `svys` to 1 and multiply it by `*b` each time?

Comment: will result in output 1 no matter what numbers i enter.

Comment: Watch out for your calling code - see my edit. Just pass `b` and `n` now you changed the function, not their addresses.

Comment: I have rollbacked your inclusion of the solution in your question: please post it as an answer of its own instead, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

long long intpow(int a, int b)
{
    long long tempres = 1;
    while(b--) 
        tempres *= a;
    return tempres;
}

int main(void) {

    printf("%lld\n", intpow(5,10));
    return 0;
}
```

you need much larger int to accommodate the result.

You can play with it yourself: https://ideone.com/4JT6NQ

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i declared upside that i cannot use pow

Comment: what pow? Do you know what you write? intpow is not the pow. It is the function written by me. You can rename it anything you want. But first of all you need a C book.

Comment: @DušoMorháč I have called it intpow as it is the integer power. Definitely not `multiplied`

Comment: I understand you now, let me try that and will let ya know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let's be explicit.

First, this

```
void multiplied(int *b, int *n)
```

returns an int, so say so.

```
int multiplied(int *b, int *n)
```

Next, you initialised variables in main: do the same here.

```
  int i, vys;
```

Like this:

```
  int i=1, vys=1;
```

Now let's look at the loop:

```
  while (i<=n)
  {
    vys=*b**b;

    i++;
  }
```

As it stands, you are setting `vys` to something over and over again in the loop.
You want to multiply up, e.g. 2, then 2*2, then 2*2*2, .... if you want a power of two:

```
  while (i<=n)
  {
    vys *= *b;

    i++;
  }
```

Now, you don't need to pass pointers.

```
int multiplied(int b, int n)
{
  int i=1, vys=1;
  while (i<=n)
  {
    vys *= b;

    i++;
  }
  return vys;
}
```

---

**Edit:**

Watch out for when you call the function:

```
main(void)
{
   int b=0, n=0, vys;

   //input and checking code as you have it

    multiplied(&b, &n); //<---- return ignored
    printf("%d", vys); //<-- print uninitialsed local variable
}
```

Change you last two lines:

```
    vys = multiplied(&b, &n); //<---- return captured
    printf("%d", vys); //<-- print returned variable
```

---

**Edit 2:**

With the change to use `int` in the function and not pointers, pass the ints not their addresses:

```
    vys = multiplied(b, n); //<---- pass the ints not their addresses
    printf("%d", vys); //<-- print returned variable, which should vary now
```

Comment: i still get this output:       0     i can add any number i want... I guess it has to do something with vys in main.. whenever i change it to any number i get that number in output so for e.g. vys=1 output would be:    1           Any solutions?

Comment: still getting same output

Comment: It looks like you have changed the code in your question now - making my answer look a bit foolish! - I'll add one more edit to match what you say you currently. have.

Comment: Originally the multiply function took `int * b` and `int * n` and used `vys = *b**b;` As `main` stands (at the moment) it is passing the address of local varaibles to the new improved function that no longer takes pointers. But the calling ccode still passes addresses.

Comment: Don't you understand thew he does not know that the pointer is. He's just seen it in the scanf before :).

Comment: I added pointers from your edit now i get this output for numbers 5 and 2: -747095695

Comment: I think we need to start again with a new question! The various edits now me I'm not sure what code you really have. Try some print statements yourself to see what is going on. You can amange to figure this out. The `&` takes the address of a variable - giving you a pointer. I suggested removing these since we don't need them. Do you actually have `vys = multiplied(b, n);`? Try printing stuff in your function. See if you have any warnings when you write the code.

Comment: I did some random stuff cuz I had no idea what else can I do and it works now :D I removed pointers and & from main and woila... THANKS TO EVERYONE WHO TRYED TO HELP :-)! I appreciate that alot!